# Failing to compile Cyanogen Trebuchet Launcher, NDK build problems

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, cyanogenmod

I am trying to compile the **Trebuchet launcher from Cyanogen**. I have installed **Cygwin** and the **Android NDK library**. 
I need to compile the Android.mk in the root project and then the application. Clearly I am doing something wrong and failing. 
**Ps. The project can be cloned from github**
Link `https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_packages_apps_Trebuchet`

**What I have done:**

**Went to the project root directory from the Cygwin program**

```
Arlind@DESKTOP-OIN7IUU ~
$ cd /cygdrive/c/Users/Arlind/Desktop/Trebouche
```

**Exported the path**

```
Arlind@DESKTOP-OIN7IUU /cygdrive/c/Users/Arlind/Desktop/Trebouche
$ export NDK_PROJECT_PATH=.
```

**Tried to run the Mk file with**

```
Arlind@DESKTOP-OIN7IUU /cygdrive/c/Users/Arlind/Desktop/Trebouche
$ /cygdrive/c/android-ndk-r10e/ndk-build.cmd NDK_APPLICATION_MK=Application.mk
```

**What I am getting**

```
Android.mk:95: C:/android-ndk-r10e/build/core/base_rules.mk: No such    file or directory
C:/android-ndk-r10e/build/core/build-all.mk:89: Android NDK: WARNING:   There are no modules to build in this project!
make.exe: *** No rule to make target `C:/android-ndk-r10e/build/core/base_rules.mk'.  Stop.
```

**Full Log Output**

```
 Arlind@DESKTOP-OIN7IUU /cygdrive/c/Users/Arlind/Desktop/Trebouche
$ /cygdrive/c/android-ndk-r10e/ndk-build.cmd NDK_APPLICATION_MK=./Application.mk                                                                                                                                                  -d
GNU Make 3.81
Copyright (C) 2006  Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

This program built for i586-pc-mingw32
find_and_set_shell setting default_shell = cmd
Reading makefiles...
Reading makefile `C:\android-ndk-r10e\build/core/build-local.mk'...
Reading makefile `C:/android-ndk-r10e/build/core/init.mk' (search path) (no ~ ex                                                                                                                                                 pansion)...
Creating temporary batch file C:\cygwin64\tmp\make8496-1.bat
CreateProcess(C:\cygwin64\tmp\make8496-1.bat,C:\cygwin64\tmp\make8496-1.bat,...)
Main thread handle = 000000000000009C
Cleaning up temporary batch file C:\cygwin64\tmp\make8496-1.bat
CreateProcess(C:\android-ndk-r10e\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\awk.exe,C:/android                                                                                                                                                 -ndk-r10e/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/awk.exe -f C:/android-ndk-r10e/build/awk/c                                                                                                                                                 heck-awk.awk,...)
Reading makefile `C:/android-ndk-r10e/build/core/definitions.mk' (search path) (                                                                                                                                                 no ~ expansion)...
Reading makefile `C:/android-ndk-r10e/build/gmsl/gmsl' (search path) (no ~ expan                                                                                                                                                 sion)...
Reading makefile `C:/android-ndk-r10e/build/gmsl/__gmsl' (search path) (no ~ exp                                                                                                                                                 ansion)...
Reading makefile `C:/android-ndk-r10e/build/core/definitions-tests.mk' (search p                                                                                                                                                 ath) (no ~ expansion)...
Reading makefile `C:/android-ndk-r10e/build/core/definitions-utils.mk' (search p                                                                                                                                                 ath) (no ~ expansion)...
Reading makefile `C:/android-ndk-r10e/build/core/definitions-host.mk' (search pa                                                                                                                                                 th) (no ~ expansion)...
Reading makefile `C:/android-ndk-r10e/build/core/definitions-graph.mk' (search p                                                                                                                                                 ath) (no ~ expansion)...
Reading makefile `C:/android-ndk-r10e/build/core/add-platform.mk' (search path)                                                                                                                                                  (no ~ expansion)...
Reading makefile `C:/android-ndk-r10e/build/core/add-platform.mk' (search path)                                                                                                                                                  (no ~ expansion)...
Reading makefile `C:/android-ndk-r10e/build/core/add-platform.mk' (search path)                                                                                                                                                  (no ~ expansion)...
Reading makefile `C:/android-ndk-r10e/build/core/add-platform.mk' (search path)                                                                                                                                                  (no ~ expansion)...
Reading makefile `C:/android-ndk-r10e/build/core/add-platform.mk' (search path)                                                                                                                                                  (no ~ expansion)...
Reading makefile `C:/android-ndk-r10e/build/core/add-platform.mk' (search path)                                                                                                                                                  (no ~ expansion)...
Reading makefile `C:/android-ndk-r10e/build/core/add-platform.mk' (search path)                                                                                                                                                  (no ~ expansion)...
Reading makefile `C:/android-ndk-r10e/build/core/add-platform.mk' (search path)                                                                                                                                                  (no ~ expansion)...
Reading makefile `C:/android-ndk-r10e/build/core/add-platform.mk' (search path)                                                                                                                                                  (no ~ expansion)...
Reading makefile `C:/android-ndk-r10e/build/core/add-platform.mk' (search path)                                                                                                                                                  (no ~ expansion)...
Reading makefile `C:/android-ndk-r10e/build/core/add-platform.mk' (search path)                                                                                                                                                  (no ~ expansion)...
Reading makefile `C:/android-ndk-r10e/build/core/add-platform.mk' (search path)                                                                                                                                                  (no ~ expansion)...
Reading makefile `C:/android-ndk-r10e/build/core/add-platform.mk' (search path)                                                                                                                                                  (no ~ expansion)...
Reading makefile `C:/android-ndk-r10e/build/core/add-platform.mk' (search path)                                                                                                                                                  (no ~ expansion)...
Reading makefile `C:/android-ndk-r10e/build/core/add-toolchain.mk' (search path)                                                                                                                                                  (no ~ expansion)...
Reading makefile `C:/android-ndk-r10e/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/confi                                                                                                                                                 g.mk' (search path) (no ~ expansion)...
Reading makefile `C:/android-ndk-r10e/build/core/add-toolchain.mk' (search path)                                                                                                                                                  (no ~ expansion)...
Reading makefile `C:/android-ndk-r10e/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-clang3.5/                                                                                                                                                 config.mk' (search path) (no ~ expansion)...
Reading makefile `C:/android-ndk-r10e/build/core/add-toolchain.mk' (search path)                                                                                                                                                  (no ~ expansion)...
Reading makefile `C:/android-ndk-r10e/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-clang3.6/                                                                                                                                                 config.mk' (search path) (no ~ expansion)...
Reading makefile `C:/android-ndk-r10e/build/core/add-toolchain.mk' (search path)                                                                                                                                                  (no ~ expansion)...
Reading makefile `C:/android-ndk-r10e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/confi                                                                                                                                                 g.mk' (search path) (no ~ expansion)...
Reading makefile `C:/android-ndk-r10e/build/core/add-toolchain.mk' (search path)                                                                                                                                                  (no ~ expansion)...
Reading makefile `C:/android-ndk-r10e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/confi                                                                                                                                                 g.mk' (search path) (no ~ expansion)...
Reading makefile `C:/android-ndk-r10e/build/core/add-toolchain.mk' (search path)                                                                                                                                                  (no ~ expansion)...
Reading makefile `C:/android-ndk-r10e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-clang3.5/                                                                                                                                                 config.mk' (search path) (no ~ expansion)...
Reading makefile `C:/android-ndk-r10e/build/core/add-toolchain.mk' (search path)                                                                                                                                                  (no ~ expansion)...
Reading makefile `C:/android-ndk-r10e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-clang3.6/                                                                                                                                                 config.mk' (search path) (no ~ expansion)...
Reading makefile `C:/android-ndk-r10e/build/core/add-toolchain.mk' (search path)                                                                                                                                                  (no ~ expansion)...
Reading makefile `C:/android-ndk-r10e/toolchains/llvm-3.5/config.mk' (search pat                                                                                                                                                 h) (no ~ expansion)...
Reading makefile `C:/android-ndk-r10e/build/core/add-toolchain.mk' (search path)                                                                                                                                                  (no ~ expansion)...
Reading makefile `C:/android-ndk-r10e/toolchains/llvm-3.6/config.mk' (search pat                                                                                                                                                 h) (no ~ expansion)...
Reading makefile `C:/android-ndk-r10e/build/core/add-toolchain.mk' (search path)                                                                                                                                                  (no ~ expansion)...
Reading makefile `C:/android-ndk-r10e/toolchains/mips64el-linux-android-4.9/conf                                                                                                                                                 ig.mk' (search path) (no ~ expansion)...
Reading makefile `C:/android-ndk-r10e/build/core/add-toolchain.mk' (search path)                                                                                                                                                  (no ~ expansion)...
Reading makefile `C:/android-ndk-r10e/toolchains/mips64el-linux-android-clang3.5                                                                                                                                                 /config.mk' (search path) (no ~ expansion)...
Reading makefile `C:/android-ndk-r10e/build/core/add-toolchain.mk' (search path)                                                                                                                                                  (no ~ expansion)...
Reading makefile `C:/android-ndk-r10e/toolchains/mips64el-linux-android-clang3.6                                                                                                                                                 /config.mk' (search path) (no ~ expansion)...
Reading makefile `C:/android-ndk-r10e/build/core/add-toolchain.mk' (search path)                                                                                                                                                  (no ~ expansion)...
Reading makefile `C:/android-ndk-r10e/toolchains/mipsel-linux-android-4.8/config                                                                                                                                                 .mk' (search path) (no ~ expansion)...
Reading makefile `C:/android-ndk-r10e/build/core/add-toolchain.mk' (search path)                                                                                                                                                  (no ~ expansion)...
Reading makefile `C:/android-ndk-r10e/toolchains/mipsel-linux-android-4.9/config                                                                                                                                                 .mk' (search path) (no ~ expansion)...
Reading makefile `C:/android-ndk-r10e/build/core/add-toolchain.mk' (search path)                                                                                                                                                  (no ~ expansion)...
Reading makefile `C:/android-ndk-r10e/toolchains/mipsel-linux-android-clang3.5/c                                                                                                                                                 onfig.mk' (search path) (no ~ expansion)...
Reading makefile `C:/android-ndk-r10e/build/core/add-toolchain.mk' (search path)                                                                                                                                                  (no ~ expansion)...
Reading makefile `C:/android-ndk-r10e/toolchains/mipsel-linux-android-clang3.6/c                                                                                                                                                 onfig.mk' (search path) (no ~ expansion)...
Reading makefile `C:/android-ndk-r10e/build/core/add-toolchain.mk' (search path)                                                                                                                                                  (no ~ expansion)...
Reading makefile `C:/android-ndk-r10e/toolchains/x86-4.8/config.mk' (search path                                                                                                                                                 ) (no ~ expansion)...
Reading makefile `C:/android-ndk-r10e/build/core/add-toolchain.mk' (search path)                                                                                                                                                  (no ~ expansion)...
Reading makefile `C:/android-ndk-r10e/toolchains/x86-4.9/config.mk' (search path                                                                                                                                                 ) (no ~ expansion)...
Reading makefile `C:/android-ndk-r10e/build/core/add-toolchain.mk' (search path)                                                                                                                                                  (no ~ expansion)...
Reading makefile `C:/android-ndk-r10e/toolchains/x86-clang3.5/config.mk' (search                                                                                                                                                  path) (no ~ expansion)...
Reading makefile `C:/android-ndk-r10e/build/core/add-toolchain.mk' (search path)                                                                                                                                                  (no ~ expansion)...
Reading makefile `C:/android-ndk-r10e/toolchains/x86-clang3.6/config.mk' (search                                                                                                                                                  path) (no ~ expansion)...
Reading makefile `C:/android-ndk-r10e/build/core/add-toolchain.mk' (search path)                                                                                                                                                  (no ~ expansion)...
Reading makefile `C:/android-ndk-r10e/toolchains/x86_64-4.9/config.mk' (search p                                                                                                                                                 ath) (no ~ expansion)...
Reading makefile `C:/android-ndk-r10e/build/core/add-toolchain.mk' (search path)                                                                                                                                                  (no ~ expansion)...
Reading makefile `C:/android-ndk-r10e/toolchains/x86_64-clang3.5/config.mk' (sea                                                                                                                                                 rch path) (no ~ expansion)...
Reading makefile `C:/android-ndk-r10e/build/core/add-toolchain.mk' (search path)                                                                                                                                                  (no ~ expansion)...
Reading makefile `C:/android-ndk-r10e/toolchains/x86_64-clang3.6/config.mk' (sea                                                                                                                                                 rch path) (no ~ expansion)...
Reading makefile `C:/android-ndk-r10e/build/core/add-application.mk' (search pat                                                                                                                                                 h) (no ~ expansion)...
Reading makefile `Application.mk' (search path) (no ~ expansion)...
CreateProcess(C:\android-ndk-r10e\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\awk.exe,C:/android                                                                                                                                                 -ndk-r10e/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/awk.exe -f C:/android-ndk-r10e/build/awk/e                                                                                                                                                 xtract-minsdkversion.awk ./AndroidManifest.xml,...)
CreateProcess(C:\android-ndk-r10e\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\awk.exe,C:/android                                                                                                                                                 -ndk-r10e/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/awk.exe -f C:/android-ndk-r10e/build/awk/e                                                                                                                                                 xtract-debuggable.awk ./AndroidManifest.xml,...)
Reading makefile `C:/android-ndk-r10e/build/core/setup-imports.mk' (search path)                                                                                                                                                  (no ~ expansion)...
Reading makefile `C:/android-ndk-r10e/build/core/build-all.mk' (search path) (no                                                                                                                                                  ~ expansion)...
Reading makefile `C:/android-ndk-r10e/build/core/setup-app.mk' (search path) (no                                                                                                                                                  ~ expansion)...
Reading makefile `C:/android-ndk-r10e/build/core/setup-abi.mk' (search path) (no                                                                                                                                                  ~ expansion)...
Reading makefile `C:/android-ndk-r10e/build/core/setup-toolchain.mk' (search pat                                                                                                                                                 h) (no ~ expansion)...
Reading makefile `C:/android-ndk-r10e/build/core/default-build-commands.mk' (sea                                                                                                                                                 rch path) (no ~ expansion)...
Reading makefile `C:/android-ndk-r10e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/setup                                                                                                                                                 .mk' (search path) (no ~ expansion)...
Reading makefile `C:/android-ndk-r10e/sources/cxx-stl/system/Android.mk' (search                                                                                                                                                  path) (no ~ expansion)...
Reading makefile `C:/android-ndk-r10e/build/core/clear-vars.mk' (search path) (n                                                                                                                                                 o ~ expansion)...
Reading makefile `C:/android-ndk-r10e/build/core/build-static-library.mk' (searc                                                                                                                                                 h path) (no ~ expansion)...
Reading makefile `C:/android-ndk-r10e/build/core/build-module.mk' (search path)                                                                                                                                                  (no ~ expansion)...
Reading makefile `Android.mk' (search path) (no ~ expansion)...
Reading makefile `C:/android-ndk-r10e/build/core/clear-vars.mk' (search path) (n                                                                                                                                                 o ~ expansion)...
Reading makefile `RemoteFolder/Android.mk' (search path) (no ~ expansion)...
Reading makefile `C:/android-ndk-r10e/build/core/clear-vars.mk' (search path) (n                                                                                                                                                 o ~ expansion)...
Reading makefile `RemoteFolder/Android-prebuilt-libs.mk' (searAndroid.mk:95: C:/                                                                                                                                                 android-ndk-r10e/build/core/base_rules.mk: No such file or directory
ch path) (no ~ expansion)...
Reading makefile `C:/android-ndk-r10e/build/core/clear-vars.mk' (search path) (n                                                                                                                                                 o ~ expansion)...
Reading makefile `C:/android-ndk-r10e/build/core/clear-vars.mk' (search path) (n                                                                                                                                                 o ~ expansion)...
Reading makefile `C:/android-ndk-r10e/build/core/base_rules.mk' (search path) (n                                                                                                                                                 o ~ expansion)...
Reading makefile `RemoteFolder/Android.mk' (search path) (no ~ expansion)...
Reading makefile `tests/Android.mk' (search path) (no ~ expansion)...
Reading makefile `C:/android-ndk-r10e/builC:/android-ndk-r10e/build/core/build-a                                                                                                                                                 ll.mk:89: Android NDK: WARNING: There are no modules to build in this project!                                                                                                                                                   
d/core/build-binary.mk' (search path) (no ~ expansion)...
Reading makefile `C:/android-ndk-r10e/build/core/import-locals.mk' (search path)                                                                                                                                                  (no ~ expansion)...
Updating makefiles....
 Considering target file `C:/android-ndk-r10e/build/core/import-locals.mk'.
  Looking for an implicit rule for `C:/android-ndk-r10e/build/core/import-locals                                                                                                                                                 .mk'.
  No implicit rule found for `C:/android-ndk-r10e/build/core/import-locals.mk'.
  Finished prerequisites of target file `C:/android-ndk-r10e/build/core/import-l                                                                                                                                                 ocals.mk'.
 No need to remake target `C:/android-ndk-r10e/build/core/import-locals.mk'.
 Considering target file `C:/android-ndk-r10e/build/core/build-binary.mk'.
  Looking for an implicit rule for `C:/android-ndk-r10e/build/core/build-binary.                                                                                                                                                 mk'.
  No implicit rule found for `C:/android-ndk-r10e/build/core/build-binary.mk'.
  Finished prerequisites of target file `C:/android-ndk-r10e/build/core/build-bi                                                                                                                                                 nary.mk'.
 No need to remake target `C:/android-ndk-r10e/build/core/build-binary.mk'.
 Considering target file `tests/Android.mk'.
  Looking for an implicit rule for `tests/Android.mk'.
  No implicit rule found for `tests/Android.mk'.
  Finished prerequisites of target file `tests/Android.mk'.
 No need to remake target `tests/Android.mk'.
 Considering target file `RemoteFolder/Android.mk'.
  Looking for an implicit rule for `RemoteFolder/Android.mk'.
  No implicit rule found for `RemoteFolder/Android.mk'.
  Finished prerequisites of target file `RemoteFolder/Android.mk'.
 No need to remake target `RemoteFolder/Android.mk'.
 Considering target file `C:/android-ndk-r10e/build/core/base_rules.mk'.
  File `C:/android-ndk-r10e/build/core/base_rules.mk' does not exist.
  Looking for an implicit rule for `C:/android-ndk-r10e/build/core/base_rules.mk                                                                                                                                                 '.
  No implicit rule found for `C:/android-ndk-r10e/build/core/base_rules.mk'.
  Finished prerequisites of target file `C:/android-ndk-r10e/build/core/base_rul                                                                                                                                                 es.mk'.
 Must remake target `C:/android-ndk-r10e/build/core/base_rules.mk'.
make.exe: *** No rule to make target `C:/android-ndk-r10e/build/core/base_rules.                                                                                                                                                 mk'.  Stop.
```

Comment: Since I had no more place, considering all the log output. I already searched on stack overflow for solutions and in google. I have no spaces in the directory leading to ndk, since I read that ndk is problematic regarding that one.

Comment: Is the project supposed to be built with the NDK or the full platform build system?

Comment: @RichardCritten since it gives errors in eclipse, alot of them actually and considering the Android.mk file, I suppose its the first one. Although I am open to other plans on how it should be compiled, or where I am going wrong..

Comment: @RichardCritten among many websites which I visited online, this was the suggested approach.